# Backspace in input field does not delete text for jquery ui widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Ok, I've been trying to build a basic combo box widget (a hidden select, an inputfield and a div for the options) that reacts to certain events like keypressed and focusin. Now I stumbled upon a problem, I can not delete characters in the input using backspace. I can delete with the delete key, I can go left and right with the left and right keys, but backspace does not work.

The following code shows my _create method of my jquery ui widget

Code:

```
_create: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.currentComboContainer = $("<div class='currentComboBoxContainer' ></div>");
        this.select = this.element.hide();
        this.select.wrap(this.currentComboContainer);
        var selected = this.select.children(":selected"),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $("<input />");
        this.optionsDiv = $("<div></div>");

        this.input.insertAfter(this.select)
            .addClass("currentComboBox");

        this.optionsDiv.insertAfter(this.input)
            .addClass("currentComboBox");

        this.select.children().clone().appendTo(this.optionsDiv);

        this._on(".currentComboBoxOptionElement", {
            click: this._optionClick
        });

        //this.optionsDiv.delegate(".currentComboBox", "click", this._optionClick);

        this.input.val(value)
            .focusin(function() {
                self.optionsDiv.show();
            })
            .focusout(function() {
                self.optionsDiv.delay(200).hide(0);
            })
            .dblclick(function () {
                CCNet.UI.wait(true);
                var toId = self.input.val();
                self.input.blur();
                if(toId)
                    $.post(self.options.navigationAction + "?id=" + toId);
            })
            .keyup(function (keyevent) {
                /*if (keyevent.which === 13) {
                    CCNet.UI.wait(true);
                    var toId = self.input.val();
                    self.input.blur();
                    if(toId)
                        $.post(self.options.navigationAction + "?id=" + toId);
                }*/
            });

       var inputOffset = this.input.position();
       inputOffset.top += this.input.height() + 3;
       this.optionsDiv
            .css(inputOffset)
            .hide();
    }
```

I'd appreciate any kind of input on the topic, thanks

Comment: Can you add a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: I'll try and update the question once I got it.